# Bizarre message whenever I open my calendar

Tags: calendar

This is maddening. Why does my calendar version 10.0 start out with this pop up every day???

"The URL https://calendar.google.com/calendar/dav/xxxxx@gmail.com/user/ encountered HTTP error 404. Make sure the URL is correct."

Comment: You mean other than that it cannot find the URL? That's what a 404 is, 'not found'.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are trying to access a calendar link that was created before Google changed their URL formats (which was a long time ago). Old Google calendar links started with

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/
```

Back in 2013, they changed the URL format to

```
https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/your-email
```

I would suggest that firstly, you should delete any subscribed calendars (e.g. things like the "Public Holidays" calendar. If the problem persists, the next step would be to remove your account from the calendar app entirely, close the calendar app, then reopen and re-add your account details.

Make sure you've backed up your data first.

Comment: This was my issue. I had a really old Public Holidays calendar I was following. Removed that and fixed the issue.